# how to bind List<model> to create view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a form to collect the qualifications of students. At first, the list should contain 4 objects for four different qualifications. segment of the *create view*

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
          <div class="col-md-3 me-2">
              <label asp-for="@Model[i].Institute" class="control-label col-md"></label>
              <input asp-for="@Model[i].Institute" class="form-control" />
              <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].Institute" class="text-danger"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 me-2">
              <label asp-for="@Model[i].YearGraduated" class="control-label"></label>
              <input asp-for="@Model[i].YearGraduated" class="form-control" />
              <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].YearGraduated" class="text-danger"></span>
          </div>
}

<div class="form-group d-flex-row m-auto mt-2">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save and Continue"/>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new List<Qualification>();
    model = _context.Qualifications.ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

And this is the model class:

```
public partial class Qualification
{
    public Qualification()
    {
        Subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();
    }
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Institute { get; set; } = null!;
    public short YearGraduated { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set;
}
```

My problem is when I run the code, nothing is generated and no error at all.

Can anyone help?

Comment: where is `Model`

Comment: I saw you edited it to hard code 4, but still same question, where is Model?

Comment: IMHO, don't hard code 4 when querying, but you might want to limit to 4 on saving.. Did you need to query for a single student? `_context.Qualifications.Where(q => q.StudentId == .....)`

Comment: still no `Model` anywhere in sight

Comment: @JeremyLakeman originally the loop had `Model.Count` then OP made an edit to take it out for some reason. Still no sign of showing what 'Model' is tho

Comment: Shouldn't your `Controller` method look like this: `public IActionResult Create(Qualification qualification)` to get your form data from the `View` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you missing in your code.

```
@model List<Qualification>  // declare on top of the file
    @if(Model !=null){
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
                  <div class="col-md-3 me-2">
          <label asp-for="@Model[i].Institute" class="control-label col-md"></label>
          <input asp-for="@Model[i].Institute" class="form-control" />
          <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].Institute" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 me-2">
          <label asp-for="@Model[i].YearGraduated" class="control-label"></label>
          <input asp-for="@Model[i].YearGraduated" class="form-control" />
          <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].YearGraduated" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
        }
    }
```